# Why won't DocuSign return url of Recipientview for recipients other than myself?

Tags: php, json, post, docusignapi

I have a demo development DocuSign account, as I am trying to work with the API so that recipients can be directed to documents to sign from a sender (the sender in this case is me). Whenever I `POST` to the API to get the recipient view of a document I sent to myself, it is successful, and the url is properly returned. However, when I request a url for a recipient to anyone other than myself, I get a `400 Bad Call` error. I am implementing this in PHP, but I have also tried this on the REST API explorer to the same result.

Here is the code that works when sending documents to myself. `$account_id`, `$envelope_id`, `$recipient` are found through a database and are returning the correct values, so assume they are correct where you see them:

```
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/".$account_id."/envelopes/$envelope_id/views/recipient";

$body = array("returnUrl" => "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
                "authenticationMethod" => "None", 
                "email" => "$recipient",
                "userName" => "$recipient");

$body_string = json_encode($body);

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($body_string),
    "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"
));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_string);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($status != 201){
    die('Could not connect to end point: '.mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

This returns the following JSON:

```
{
    "url": "www.urlexample.com"
}
```

Since recipients are not authorized by default, when requesting for a recipient other than myself, I have to change the `$body` to not only include `"authenticationMethod"` and `"returnUrl"`, but also `"userId"` and `"recipientId"`, which should match, and `"clientUserId"` (which would be my developer userId) so that DocuSign knows this request is being made with authorization. However, I can't seem to make this happen.

This is what I have tried for `$body`:

```
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/".$account_id."/envelopes/$envelope_id/views/recipient";

$body = array("authenticationMethod" => "email",
              "clientUserId" => "314c7a19-49ff-4405-a958-42344273060c",
              "returnUrl" => "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
              "recipientId" => "a3f182e7-65b6-4bc1-b603-cc8ed23fed0d"
              "userId" => "a3f182e7-65b6-4bc1-b603-cc8ed23fed0d"
        );
```

This request (substituted into the previous code) returns a `400` error with the following JSON:

```
{
    "errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ENVELOPE_RECIPIENT",
    "message": "The recipient you have identified is not a valid recipient of the specified envelope."
}
```

However this doesn't make any sense, because both `"recipientId"` and `"userId"` match, and the `$envelope_id` is also definitely correct (I triple checked).

**BOTTOM LINE:** How do I generate urls for recipient views if the recipients are not authorized?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the envelope has been "sent" and isn't in "created" status. Try passing username & E-mail that match the recipient on the envelope that was created, corresponding to name & e-mail.  ClientUserId if present on the original creation of the envelope must also match.

If that isn't it - please post how you are creating the envelope. The best way to do so is to capture the raw API request logs and post the JSON: https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging

Comment: This is an API system that clients will be using to send Documents to their customers. I will not be creating/controlling any of the Admin accounts, but I will have their account information to keep track of all envelopes they create and send. They will be creating envelopes from templates on their website accounts. I can retrieve any information I want about any of the clients, envelopes, or receivers, I just need to know what exactly I am missing here.

Comment: The recipient view is 100% dependent upon how the envelope was created. Would need to see what the envelope creation API request looked like. If it wasn't created from the API then you cannot generate a recipient view token.

Comment: Yes you can, as I ended up being able to.

Answer (score 0):

To generate signing tokens for recipients in a given envelope one of the following needs to be true:

1. You need to be the sender of the envelope.
2. You need to be an Admin of the sending account.

Can you confirm one of the following are true in your case?

Comment: Both are true in my case